# Determine $f_k(n)$ in $\sum_{i=0}^n \left (1-\frac{1}{2^i} \right )^k - f_k(n) \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

For a given $k \in \mathbb{N}$, could you determine $f_k(n)$ such that the following holds?

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \left (1-\frac{1}{2^i} \right )^k - f_k(n) \rightarrow 0$$

For $k=1$,

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n \left (1-\frac{1}{2^i} \right )=n-2.$$

Hence, $f_1(n)=n-2$.

Comment: Apply the binomial formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(1-2^{-i})^k=\sum_{i=1}^n(1-2^{-i})^k=\sum_{i=1}^n\left [1+\sum_{l=1}^k{k\choose l}(-1)^l2^{-il}\right ]\\
=n+\sum_{l=1}^k{k\choose l}(-1)^l\sum_{i=1}^n2^{-il}=n+\sum_{l=1}^k{k\choose l}(-1)^l{2^{-l}\,[1-2^{-nl}]\over 1- 2^{-l}}$$
Hence $$f_k(n)=n+\sum_{l=1}^k{k\choose l}(-1)^l{1\over 2^l- 1}$$
In particular $f_1(n)=n-1.$

**Another solution**
By the limit test the following series is convergent
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty [1-(1-2^{-i})^k]$$ as
$$\lim_{i\to \infty}{1-(1-2^{-i})^k\over 2^{-i}}\underset{x:=1-2^{-i}}{\quad =\quad }\lim_{x\to 1}{1-x^k\over 1-x}=k$$
Hence
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n(1-2^{-i})^k-n=-\sum_{i=1}^n[1-(1-2^{-i})^k]\underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} -\sum_{i=1}^\infty [1-(1-2^{-i})^k]$$
Thus
$$f_k(n)=n-\sum_{i=1}^\infty [1-(1-2^{-i})^k]$$

Comment: Thank you! Can the summation in $f_k(n)$ be further simplified?

Comment: I have no idea. I have re-edited to include another form of $f_k$ but this time it is represented as an infinite series.

Comment: Nice formula! I am now struggling to find the limit of a function involving the above function. You may also check https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4818277/1231520?