# Limit of a parametric function: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left ( 1- 2^{-i}t \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

For fixed $0<t<2$, could you compute the limit of $g_t(n)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

$$ g_t(n)=2^{-\frac{n(n-1)}{4} } \left ( 1- \frac{t}{2^n} \right)^{-\frac{n}{2}} e^{\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(n,k) \left ( 1- \frac{t}{2^n} \right)^{-k}} $$

with

$$ f(n,k)=\frac{1}{2k} \sum_{i=1}^n  \left ( 1- \frac{1}{2^{n-i}} \right)^{k}? $$

Using the answer provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4818196/1231520), for the function $f(n,k)$ we have

$$2kf(n,k)-n \rightarrow -1+\sum_{l=1}^k{k\choose l}(-1)^l{1\over 2^l- 1}=-1-\sum_{i=1}^\infty [1-(1-2^{-i})^k].$$

The function $g_t(n)$ is **originally** defined as:

$$ g_t(n)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} \left ( 1- \frac{t}{2^{i}} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$

I **guess** working with the first formula of $g_t(n)$ may be easier than the above original formula.

**Motivation:** The function $g_t(n)=\mathbb E(e^{tS_n})$ is the moment generating function of $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$, where $X_i\sim \Gamma \left ( \frac{1}{2}, 2^{-i} \right )$ and all $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are independent. The first formula of $g_t(n)$ follows from the general formula (2.6) in Moschopoulos (1985) [2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02481123).

I want to determine the distribution of $S_\infty$, which has finite mean $\frac{1}{2}$ and variance $\frac{1}{6}$, and generalizations of CLT cannot be applied to it.

Note that $$g_0(n)=2^{-\frac{n(n-1)}{4} }  e^{\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(n,k) }=\mathbb E(e^{0 \times S_n})=1$$ for any $n$. Based on this and using the Napier's constant, I obtain the limit as 1, which seems to be incorrect.

The mgf of $S_\infty$ (if exists) is greater than $e^{\frac{1}{2}t}$ by the Jensen's inequality and $\mathbb E(S_\infty)=1/2$.

Comment: I see you have got one downvote. Perhaps you should provide some motivation why this particular expression is interesting.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I just added a motivation. Hope you support my question!

Comment: I have upvoted your post. The task looks hard at first sight.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you! I agree it seems very challenging. I provided some extra observations that may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no formula for the infinite product $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1- 2^{-i}t )^{-1/2}$$

You may simplify it by noting that $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1- 2^{-i}t )^{-1/2}=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1- 2^{-i}t) \right)^{-1/2}$$

and the product $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1- 2^{-i}t )$ can be written in terms of [the $q$-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) as $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1- 2^{-i}t )=\frac{(t,1/2)_\infty}{1-t}$$

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Is there any hope that this can be found? or There is a proof that -Pochhammer numbers cannot be explicitly computed in general (e.g., by the Abel's theorem, the roots of fifth-degree polynomial equations cannot be obtained explicitly)?  In the first case, could you explain why it is not expected to be found?

Comment: @Amir I think it hasn't been proved that this functions can't be written in terms of elementary functions, but since they are used in some extensively studied fields of Mathematics, I'd say is highly improbable that they turn out to be elementary.